# How to use Xamarin profiler for VS2017 Professional edition

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, profiler

We are developing mobile app using xamarin.forms with VS2017 Professional edition.

Can I use Xamarin profiler with VS 2017? (as page https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/profiler/ page says it can only be used with enterprize edition).

If not what are other alternatives.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Xamarin Profiler doesn't work without VS Enterprise
2. I would suggest you check [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19074/profiling-tools) discussion out, it will help you with what the xamarin community thinks about profiling and what tools do they usually prefer for profiling.

Goodluck!